# Improved spacing in vote-to-close dialog

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, vote-to-close, close-dialog

When voting to close a question that has multiple reasons the spacing between the preamble and the list of possibilities doesn't look appropriate:

[image]

Understandably the unordered list in the top and the bottom (when clicking the `(more)` button) is the same, and that's good. However, I'd suggesting adding more space between the "This question has been flagged as:" and the first item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spacing in the vote-to-close dialog has been updated and now resembles

[image]